# Heap error when using findContours openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, heap-memory

I read a lot of posts but I still can't find a solution to my problem. The linked libraries are correct and the code works fine a lot of other openCV functions but not for findContours.
I'm going to post my code:

```
int check_broken(Mat src, Mat check){
vector<Mat> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
Mat check_gray,check_g;
cvtColor(src,check_gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(check_gray,check_g,100,255,THRESH_BINARY);
namedWindow("ventana",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("ventana",check_gray);
waitKey(0);

Mat dst(check.rows,check.cols,CV_8UC1,Scalar::all(0));
int count = 0;

findContours( check_g, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );


for (int i = 0; i < contours.size() ; i = hierarchy[i][0]){
    Rect r = boundingRect(contours[i]);
    if(hierarchy[i][2]<0){
        rectangle(check,Point(r.x,r.y), Point(r.x+r.width,r.y+r.height),Scalar(0,0,255),3,8,0);
        count++;
    }
}
namedWindow("ventana",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("ventana",dst);
waitKey(0);
destroyWindow("ventana");
return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling in Release mode and all the libraries are of the same version 2413 and I'm working with VS10. I'm wondering how to deal with this problem. Thanks for help!

Comment: Your linked libraries are **NOT** correct. Be sure not to use debug libs in release mode, or viceversa. And use the same architecture (x86 vs x64) as your project. And be sure that the OpenCV libs are compiled with vc10

Comment: opencv_calib3d2413.lib
opencv_contrib2413.lib
opencv_core2413.lib
opencv_features2d2413.lib
opencv_flann2413.lib
opencv_gpu2413.lib
opencv_highgui2413.lib
opencv_imgproc2413.lib
opencv_legacy2413.lib
opencv_ml2413.lib
opencv_nonfree2413.lib
opencv_objdetect2413.lib
opencv_photo2413.lib
opencv_stitching2413.lib
opencv_superres2413.lib
opencv_ts2413.lib
opencv_video2413.lib
opencv_videostab2413.lib 

These are the libs linked for the release mode, I'm sure they are correct

Comment: These are release libraries. Be sure to run your code in release. Also please show the path where these libraries are

Comment: I'm sure to run in release. Here is the path: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin

Comment: You're using OpenCV compiled with vc11 (i.e. Visual Studio 2012). So it's **not** going to work. You can either 1) use Visual Studio 2012, or 2) use OpenCV compiled with vc10 (if you don't find prebuilt binaries, you need to recompile OpenCV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm working with VS10
>
> Here is the path: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin

**You're linking to the wrong libraries.**

You're using OpenCV compiled with `vc11` (i.e. Visual Studio 2012), but you're using Visual Studio 2010. So it's not going to work. You can either:

1. use Visual Studio 2012, or
2. use OpenCV compiled with `vc10` (if you don't find prebuilt binaries, you need to recompile OpenCV)